# How we can maintain the state of logged in and loggedout users and share that state to homepage in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Here after successfull login im directing to homepage. But how can show whether the user is logged in or loggedout in homepage.here i have attached my codesanbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-rain-olm7wx?file=/src/components/Home.component.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const loginAction = {
    login,
};
function login(user) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        var data = {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
        };
        axios
            .post('https://reqres.in/api/login', data)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("res", (res));
                alert("response " + JSON.stringify(res.data));
                dispatch(setUserLogin(res.data, false));
                localStorage.setItem("isLogin", true)
                window.location.pathname = "./";
            })
            .catch(err => {

                dispatch(setUserLoginError(err, true));
                alert("error" + err);

            });

    };
}

export function setUserLogin(token, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS',
        token: token,
        isLoading: false,
        showError: showError,
    };
}

export function setUserLoginError(error, showError) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_LOGIN_ERROR',
        error: error,
        showError: showError,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are working with redux so following code will help you to confirm user logged in or logged out

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function Home() {
 
  // https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks
  const isLogin = useSelector((state) => state.login.isLogin)
  console.log('isLogin ',isLogin);

  return (
    <>
      <div>This is homepage</div>
      <br />
      <a href="/login">
        <button> LOGIN</button>
      </a>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here `useSelector` hook available from `react-redux` which you already have in your project. And `isLogin` boolean value you can read from redux store if it is `true` means user logged in and it it is `false` means user not logged in.

You can set this `isLogin` from your login component using `reducer`.

### Update 1

In your reducer I can see you have not set `isLogin` set it as following:

```
const initialState = {
    token: '',
    showError: false,
    error: '',
    isLogin: false,
    isLoading: false
};

export function login(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                token: action.token,
                isLogin: true,
                isLoading: action.isLoading,
                showError: action.showError,
            };
        case 'SET_LOGIN_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.error,
                showError: action.showError,
                isLogin: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

### Update 2

You are getting `isLogin` false in App.js because you of `window.location.pathname = "./";` in `loginAction.js` It will reload the page and so `isLogin` will reset so remove it first.

Instead you can try following code in `Login.jsx`

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function Login(props) {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const isLogin = useSelector((state) => state.login.isLogin)
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isLogin){
      navigate('/')
    }
    
  },[isLogin])
}
```

Comment: it is showing isLogin as false after we logged in also.

Comment: Check I have edited my answer, in Reducer you have to set `isLogin : true` on Success login

Comment: yes after i changed also it is not working

Comment: Check now I again edited the answer , now it will work

Comment: @vinothiniKB is it working now ? Because I already confirm the output codesandbox it is working on my side.